# I am looking for a word that means "forcible exposure or revelation"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an American English word meaning "the forcible exposure or revelation" of something. The context I have in mind is something similar to the leak of documents by a whistleblower or the like. A negative or destructive connotation isn't necessary, but would be appropriate.

Alternative meanings come to mind here (if this doesn't just confuse things):

1. a word meaning "the exposure of some body of information or other contents"
2. a word meaning "the revelation of the contents of some entity"

I think it's really #2 that I'm after, so that an example sentence describing the leak of, e.g., tax records, might be something like "the ______ of the IRS."

*Despoliation* comes to mind, but that isn't right. Grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Not a single word, but "the airing of the IRS's dirty laundry" might work.

Comment: It's called [Freedom of Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_Information_Act_%28United_States%29), but the phrase sits awkwardly with your IRS sample sentence. You could say "the *solicitation of information* from the IRS pursuant to the Freedom of Information Act", but this is also a significant modification of your sample sentence. (NB: this assumes you're after the legally-enforced requirement to reveal information - it's *like*, but it's *not*, an unauthorised leak by a whistleblower.)

Comment: that is close @samgak, thank you, but I'm really looking for a word that has the entity (in this example the IRS) as its object. airing --> dirty laundry, spilling --> secrets, etc., and most of the other things I've been able to think of all have the contents themselves as the object. I wonder if there's a word that describes the opening of the container.

Comment: I don't have any good answers for you, but a couple of potential leads: (1) Undercover law enforcement officers speak of their cover being "blown" when their identities are revealed.  (2) I believe that this has dropped in popularity and acceptability over the past couple of decades, but, for a while, "out" was used as a verb, meaning to reveal that a person was homosexual.  For example: "The gossip columnist outed the famous singer."  (This was a reference to forcing the person to "come out of the closet".)

Comment: Do you mean "making something public" (or availbale to the public) or do you refer to "public dissemination"?

Answer (score 1):

The exposure of something previously secret is known as [*disclosure*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+disclosure).

This applies to both forced and unforced revelations.